# Transferring data from Ubuntu install to WSL Ubuntu

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a Ubuntu work laptop that I have already been using for a few weeks. I have been offered to have Windows installed on my laptop. Is it possible to transfer all files and data from the existing Ubuntu install to WSL Ubuntu if Windows is installed?

Comment: Will Windows be installed to dual-boot with Ubuntu, or are you thinking of replacing Ubuntu entirely with Windows/WSL when it is installed?

Comment: Also, what files and data are you referring to?  Is everything that you have worked on in your `/home/<user>` directory, or could there be files outside that?  What mail application have you been using and do you need to back any local mail, or is the mail all still on the server?  Do you need any logs to be backed up?  Etc., etc.

Comment: Just install windows on a separate partition and keep Ubuntu.

Comment: Ideally I would replace Ubuntu entirely with WSL, and not have a dual-boot. There are some files outside of /home/<user>, mainly apt packages and other programs that if really necessary can be re-downloaded and re-installed. Gmail is used for work, so that's not something to worry about.

Comment: I am using a desktop environment, but the programs I need Ubuntu for are command-line anyways. All the GUI apps I currently use on Ubuntu have Windows versions.